# Pyspark improving performance for multiple column operations

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have written a class which performs standard scaling over grouped data.

```
class Scaler:
.
.
.
.
def __transformOne__(self, df_with_stats, newName, colName):
    return df_with_stats\
            .withColumn(newName, 
                        (F.col(colName)-F.col(f'avg({colName})'))/(F.col(f'stddev_samp({colName})')+self.tol))\
            .drop(colName)\
            .withColumnRenamed(newName, colName)
    
def transform(self, df):
    df_with_stats = df.join(....) #calculate stats here by doing a groupby and then do a join
    
    return reduce(lambda df_with_stats, kv: self.__transformOne__(df_with_stats, *kv), 
                   self.__tempNames__(), df_with_stats)[df.columns]
```

The idea is to save the mean and variances in columns and simply do a column subtraction/division on the column i want to scale. This part is done in the function `transformOne`. So basically its an arithmetic operation on one column.

If i want to scale multiple columns I just call the function `transformOne` multiple times but a bit more efficiently using `functools.reduce` (see the function `transform`. The class works fast enough for a single column but when I have multiple columns it takes too much time.

I have no idea about internals of spark so im a complete newbie. Is there a way i can improve this computation over multiple columns ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution does a lot of calls to `withColumn` function. Hence i changed the solution by using `select` instead of `withColumn`. There is substantial difference in the physical plans of both the approaches. For my application I improved from 15 minutes to 2 minutes using `select`. More information about this in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59789689/spark-dag-differs-with-withcolumn-vs-select).